# Cannot seem to make my else statement work properly in Python-turtle

Tags: python, if-statement, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

sorry I am a bit of a beginner and I am having trouble gettin the else statement working properly in this program i made to draw stuff in turtle with python. I tried indenting the else statement`else: print("Wrong input!")`but then it just says "Wrong input!" Everytime i do something; the program works fine but that keeps repeating. If i keep the else statement like that and I type anything else then the "Wrong input!" that is supposed to pop up doesn't appear. Anyone know what to do?

For example:
If i run the code like how i gave it here this is how it turns out:

**what you want to do?: f (<-- I input this)**

**How many pixels you want to go forward?: 100 (<-- I input this)**

and now if i put something else

**what you want to do?: asbfaifb (<-- I input this)**

**what you want to do?:**

it doesnt show the "Wrong input!" message that is supposed to say

On the other hand if I indent the else statement one more time this is the outcome

**What you want to do?: f**

**How many pixels you want to go forward?: 100**

**Wrong input!**

**What you want to do?: r**

**How many degrees you want to turn right?: 90**

**Wrong input!**

**What you want to do?: 100**

**Wrong input!**

**What you want to do?: b**

**Wrong input!**

**What you want to do?:**

but the code still runs fine, it just keeps repeating the "Wrong input!" over and over

```
#importing turle
import turtle

#Creating our turtle and naming it
turtle = turtle.Turtle()


#Ask the user what to do and tell the instructions
#Make a function for the instructions
def instructions():
  print("What do you want me to do? Please choose the letter corresponding to the action: ")
  print("Forward = f")
  print("Turn right = r")
  print("Turn left = l")
  print("Turn backwards = b")
  print("If you want to stop: stop\n")

#print out the instuctions
instructions()

#Function for drawing by getting the user's input
def drawing():
  while True:
    user = input("What you want to do?: ")
  
  #If they want to go forward
    if user == "f":
      l = int(input("How many pixels you want to go forward?: "))
      turtle.forward(l)
  
  #If they want to turn right
    elif user == "r":
      x = int(input("How many degrees you want to turn right?: "))
      turtle.right(x)
  
  #If they want to turn left
    elif user == "l":
      y = int(input("How many degrees you want to turn left?: "))
      turtle.left(y)
  
  #If they want to turn backwards
    elif user == "b":
      z = 180
      turtle.right(z)
      
  #If they want to stop the program
    if user == "stop":
      print("\nOk, I will stop the program now\n\nTo make a new drawing, re-run the program")
      break
  #If they type anything else
   else:
     print("Wrong input!")



drawing()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`else` follows the last `if` or `elif` statement before it. For you, this is:

`if user == "stop":`

Which means, if user is not "stop", you are telling the program to print "wrong input".

An easy fix is to simply change `if user == "stop":` to `elif user == "stop":`